# Search for a field in an entity passing an array of fields

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

Im trying to perform a search using Hibernate Criterias to be able to search for a field in a entity passing an array of values. For example : you have a entity USER that has a CAR or a list of CAR´s. Then I want to perform a search where I can chose several different cars and retrieve all users that have one of the cars that I listed...
Does anyone know how to do that using Hibernate Criteria?

Using JSF, Hibernate, MySQL

Thanks for you time.

Comment: Put some code whatever you tried

Comment: You are looking for an example query?

Comment: @TBM, I didnt get even close to archiving that goal.. What i do now is just compare a field against a field... using like...

Answer (score 0):

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<String> userList(String car){
    Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT table.user FROM table WHERE table.car = :car");
    query.setParameter("car", car);
    List<String> queryResults = query.getResultList();
    return queryResults;
}
```

This query will return all users that own the specified car.

Comment: Hey Jordan! I think i didnt explain myself very well... what i mean to do is pass as an argument a list of strings and return all objects that contains any of those strings...

Comment: My code is not way too far off, but the query might be very slow.